# Find out if HDD is GPT or MBT in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

How would you find out if a hard drive type is GPT or MBR with C#? I looked at Win32_DiskDrive and that doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840870/detect-gpt-and-mbr-partitions-with-powershell

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to use PInvoke (see http://pinvoke.net) with `CreateFile`, `DeviceIoControl` (`dwIoControlCode = IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX`), and the `PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX` structure's `PartitionStyle` field will tell you (`PARTITION_STYLE_MBR`, `PARTITION_STYLE_GPT` or `PARTITION_STYLE_RAW`).