# How to find if disk is GPT using python on Windows?

Tags: python, guid-partition-table

I am on windows 7 and installed python 3.5. I would like to know if the disk/ partition supplied to the program is GPT or not. I am aware of the gdisks windows package and my attempt to use it made my USB disk corrupt. I need to just find the type of disk and I am not going to carry out any operation on it. Is there a way to find it under python?
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: You might be able to execute the Windows `diskpart` command and pass it a script (text file) with the commands "list disk" in it. This produces output showing which disks are GPT which could then be parsed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35691056/355230) which shows the format of the output.

Comment: From what I've just found, you could call the Windows [`DeviceIoControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) function and pass it the control code [`IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365180(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a [`PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365448(v=vs.85).aspx) structure back that contains a field named `PartitionStyle` that has the information you want.

Comment: The previous suggestion looks good . Can you give some sample code for second suggestion so that I can accept it as an answer.